# What does the "-s" in a Perl if block do?

Tags: perl

I have a block of code as such:

```
if ( ! -s $fh ) {
    ...more code
}
```

I just need to know what the "-s" means!

Comment: Just to add, I'm guessing the ! is false, like other languages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`-s $fh` checks file size of `$fh`, so `! -s $fh` tests if file size has length zero (or there is no such file).

`$fh` can be file name, or file handle (check [perldoc -f -X](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)).

Note that this is not the same as `-z $fh`, as it won't return true for non existing files.

Comment: Great, so by that logic the if statement equates to TRUE if $fh has no size?

Comment: I believe, the closest test op that  gets to `-s` would be `-e`. Both checks for existences only former checks it by size.